# How to solve this error of Oracle apex- 1403-no data found

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I am new at oracle apex. just a beginner try to make an application using tutorials. But I got error when i create a report form and click on **edit icon** then 1403 error occurs. I'm doings all the things right. And table has data also. it is not empty.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No data found probably relates to a problem with the automatic row process not returning results. While there may be data, the page item you refer to in the where clause may not be populated as expected.

Check your session state to see if a value is present, and the url used to open the page to ensure a value was sent to the page, eg:
./ords/f?p=102:31:14107262841235::NO:RP:**P31_IDENTITY_ID:582708**

Comment: #ScottWe Please help me to solve this problem. I've checked the session state it provides the url. and I am unable to do anything with it.

Comment: I recommend you paste your URL, everything from f?p=

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this a few times too, and haven't managed to get to the bottom of it. The only solution I've found is to create a new form page from scratch and link to that one instead, and delete the old one. Absolutely everything on the page can be the same, the new one will work and the old one doesn't.

I haven't seen a bug or known issue filed about this but it's very hard to replicate on demand - it seems to happen every so often for no reason that I can discern at present.